# JavaScript array to ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, coldfusion

I have an array I've created in JavaScript.  The end result comes out to element1,element2,,,element5,element6,,,element9.... etc

Once passed to ColdFusion, it removes the null elements, I end up with element1,element2,element5,element6,element9

I need to maintain these spaces, any ideas?  My problem may begin before this, to explain in more detail...

I have a form with 13 elements that are acting as a search/filter type function.  I want to "post" with AJAX, in essence, i'm using a button to call a jQuery function and want to pass the fields to a ColdFusion page, then have the results passed back.  The JavaScript array may not even be my best option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, i'm just going to post the form and reload the page, not the easiest use of ajax...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you deserializing the jS array into a list?  CF ignores empty list fields using its built-in functions.  This can be worked around by processing the text directly.  Someone has already done this for you, fortunately.  There are several functions at cflib.org, like:

- [ListFix](http://cflib.org/udf/ListFix)
- [ListLenIncNulls](http://cflib.org/udf/ListLenIncNulls)

etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In exchanging data between javascript and coldfusion have a look at using JSON.

http://www.json.org

http://www.epiphantastic.com/cfjson/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the CF ListToArray function, use the Java String methods to split the string into an array. This will maintain the empty list items.

```
<cfset jsList = "item1,item2,,item4,item5,,item6">
<cfset jsArray = jsList.split(",")>
<cfdump var="#jsArray#">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using array in JavaScript,Fine. instead of assigning by default empty value,assign some dummy value. whenever you use this array value ignore dummy value using condition.